# wcf throws ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException and the api operation completes

Tags: wcf, api, exception, clock, skew

I have a call to an API method using WCF (API running on remote server):

```
try
{
  m_serviceClient.Deposit(account, balance);          
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
  m_log.Error(msg.ToString(), exception);
}
```

I have the API server running on remote server and if I adjust the time on the server to be 7 minutes in the future, it throws the exception:

System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The security timestamp is invalid because its creation time ('2013-02-24T15:29:03.498Z') is in the future. Current time is '2013-02-24T15:23:24.159Z' and allowed clock skew is '00:05:00'.

which is fine and all, but for some reason the function "Deposit" succeeds despite the WCF exception. any idea how can this happen and how can I prevent the "Deposit" function to succeed if WCF exception occurs?